# How to invoke aws step function using Http request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have created a step function and I am trying to invoke it using an HTTP request. I am using Postman to generate authorization signature but I am getting a 403:forbidden response.

```
<InvalidSignatureException>
  <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

I am invoking https://states.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com and getting back the reponse

The Canonical String for this request should have been
'POST
/

content-length:116
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
host:states.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20170125T183745Z

content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date
488183a388ce9b63833585129e71399296c8aa0ce4108b8f90d9616c43969a97'

The String-to-Sign should have been
'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20170125T183745Z
20170125/ap-northeast-1/states/aws4_request
fb2e325f309bf455dddbc0cd389523a9aa2410523393c9dc3890dac6e93e923c'
</Message>
</InvalidSignatureException>
```

It seems i don't have permission to invoke the step function. But in the policy file I have granted the access to user for the given role:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::7640*******:user/*****",
        "Service": "states.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please help me to set this up?

Comment: Are you trying to invoke the state machine directly by sending a `POST` request to https://states.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com ? If so, you need to use the AWS SDK to start the state machine. For example with NodeJS using the [startExecution method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/StepFunctions.html#startExecution-property).

Answer (score 0):

You have `sts:AssumeRole` statement in policy but you didn't call `sts` API, did you? You call `states` API but don't have corresponding statement in policy.

Remove `sts:AssumeRole` statement.
Add following statement.

```
Effect: Allow
Action: states:StartExecution
Resource: ARN of your state machine
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the aws authentication is just not working in postman:
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3232